# What is wrong with this ASP.net DataBinding program?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I am used to writing the data on the client side, then with JavaScript, validate and submit forms to a new page on server side which updated the database and then go again.

I am thinking with programming on ASP.net, it is not a good practice to do it on client side because security is better on server side.

I am trying to do this using sqlDataSources and DataBinding unsuccessfully.

On my page I have only two input boxes. These boxes are empty.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Prueba.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="MaximaBR.com.Prueba" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                DataSourceMode="DataReader"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Data %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [idpropiedad],[propietario] 
                               FROM [dbo].[Propiedades] 
                               WHERE [idpropiedad] = 525293">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter name="idpropiedad" 
                        controlid="idpropiedadBox" propertyname="Text" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter name="propietario" 
                        controlid="propietarioBox" propertyname="Text" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:TextBox id="idpropiedadBox" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox id="propietarioBox" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read so many articles about this but my application is on WebForms, not mvc, so I would like to do it this way.

Also, I have so many fields with responsive html, so I need to not use gridview.

It seems to me that I lost the dataview and that's what I need. I got used to working with databind on Visual Basic 6.0, but here it seems a little tricky and can't get it to work.

Maybe one of my problems is that I don't understand the WebForm Cycles times for Page Loading and others cycles times like pre render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a **databound server control** to show / edit / update data. For a single row `asp:FormView` is OK.
2. You need to bind child controls to underlying fields. `Eval` for one-way binding, `Bind` for two-way binding.

The code may look like this.

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="idpropiedadBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("idpropiedad") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="propietarioBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("propietario") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceMode="DataSet"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Data%>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [idpropiedad],[propietario] FROM  [dbo].[Propiedades] WHERE [idpropiedad] = 525293 "
    UpdateCommand="update [dbo].[Propiedades] set [idpropiedad]=@idpropiedad,[propietario]=@propietario WHERE [idpropiedad] = 525293">
    <SelectParameters>
        <%--no need as select command doesn't have parameters --%>
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="idpropiedad" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="propietario" Type="String" Size="1024" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I Implemented as you say and worked fine! the next step is to receive the url parameter for idpropiedad and substitute it on Select and Update. I try last night with <%= Request.querystring["idpropiedad"] %>, but has not work as this. I need to do it by another way. I am wondering how.

Comment: I found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xt50s8kz(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN to use  <SelectParameters>
              <%--no need as select command doesn't have parameters --%>
              <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="lapropiedad" QueryStringField="idpropiedad" />
          </SelectParameters>    It worked for Select, and then add one to Update!!! It is great!!